# deleting embedded documents with mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I'm building my first app with mongoid, and am having trouble deleting an embedded resource.  I have these models:

```
class Article
 include Mongoid::Document
 field :body
 embeds_many :comments
```

etc..

```
class Comment
 include Mongoid::Document
 field :body
 embedded_in :article, :inverse_of => :comments
end
```

I don't understand why I cannot delete a comment from an article

```
    ruby-1.9.2-p290 :043 > @article.comments
    => [#<Comment _id: 4eb0e991a27d201ded000038, _type: nil, body: "foo", score: nil>] 
    ruby-1.9.2-p290 :045 > @article.comments.first.destroy
    => true 
    ruby-1.9.2-p290 :046 > @article.comments
    => [] 
    ruby-1.9.2-p290 :047 > @article.save
    => true 
    ruby-1.9.2-p290 :049 > @article.reload
    => #<Article _id: 4eb0e991a27d201ded000037, _type: nil, body: "foo", title: .... 
    ruby-1.9.2-p290 :050 > @article.comments
    => [#<Comment _id: 4eb0e991a27d201ded000038, _type: nil, body: "foo", score: nil>]
```

Calling destroy (or delete) on the embedded document appears to delete it in memory, but not from the db. Any insight would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Hi. Did you find an answer to this? Would really appreciate any help

Comment: sorry - no - this was a while ago, and I've not pursued the project

Answer (score 0):

Please post your rails version and the versions of your gems. I've checked your setup with rails 3.2.3:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.3)
1.9.3-p0 :001 > @article = Article.new(:body => 'articleBodyText')
 => #<Article _id: 4f9d90c7f15fefb3a0000001, _type: nil, body: "articleBodyText"> 
1.9.3-p0 :002 > @article.save
 => true 
1.9.3-p0 :003 > @article.comments = [Comment.new(:body => 'commentBodyText')]
 => [#<Comment _id: 4f9d90edf15fefb3a0000002, _type: nil, body: "commentBodyText">] 
1.9.3-p0 :004 > @article.save
 => true 
1.9.3-p0 :005 > @article.comments
 => [#<Comment _id: 4f9d90edf15fefb3a0000002, _type: nil, body: "commentBodyText">] 
1.9.3-p0 :006 > @article.reload
 => #<Article _id: 4f9d90c7f15fefb3a0000001, _type: nil, body: "articleBodyText"> 
1.9.3-p0 :007 > @article.comments
 => [#<Comment _id: 4f9d90edf15fefb3a0000002, _type: nil, body: "commentBodyText">] 
1.9.3-p0 :008 > @article.comments.first.destroy
 => true 
1.9.3-p0 :009 > @article.comments
 => [] 
1.9.3-p0 :010 > @article.save
 => true 
1.9.3-p0 :011 > @article.reload
 => #<Article _id: 4f9d90c7f15fefb3a0000001, _type: nil, body: "articleBodyText"> 
1.9.3-p0 :012 > @article.comments
 => [] 
1.9.3-p0 :013 >
```

Relevant parts of Gemfile:

```
gem "mongoid", "~> 2.4"
gem "bson_ext", "~> 1.5"
```

Relevant parts of Gemfile.lock:

```
rails (3.2.3)
mongo (1.6.2)
mongoid (2.4.8)
bson (1.6.2)
bson_ext (1.6.2)
```